# xamarin android alignParentRight style

Tags: android, xamarin, styles

can you tell me how can I add alignParentRight into my xml style?

```
<style name="My_Style">
    <item name="android:layout_width">fill_parent</item>
    <item name="android:layout_height">75dp</item>
    <item name="android:background">@color/Gray_75</item>
   **<item name="android:alignParentRight">true</item>**
  </style>
```

Comment: What do you want do declare in styles? `android:alignParentRight` is `RelativeLayout` feature which positioning its child `Views` inside to the right side of it.

Comment: I have a relative layout and I need for my image to align it to right

Comment: Do it inside `ImageView` like: `android:alignParentRight="true"`

Comment: yes but I need to add it programatically for dynamic and I will add only style and thats all

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> yes but I need to add it programatically for dynamic and I will add only style and thats all.

Generally you can't do that programmatically. What we can do is:

1. Create two different styles, one with `<item name="android:alignParentRight">true</item>` and the other one not, apply them to the control when it is needed. Since in which scenario of your styles will be used is not clear in your question, maybe you can look into [State List](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/drawable-resource.html#StateList).
2. I personally think it is more straight if we directly set the `Layout Parameters` in code behind, for example:

   `var parameters = btn.LayoutParameters as RelativeLayout.LayoutParams;
   parameters.AddRule(LayoutRules.AlignParentRight);`

The `btn` in this code refer to a `Button` control.